# JasperReport to add in jsp,JasperPrint can't resolve as type

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have using Eqlipse-kepler for javaEE where jasperReport i want to compile into code so lib -common-digest,common-logger,common-collection,mysql-connector-5.0.8,jasperreport4.1,jasper-compiler-jdt has been added but still to compile the Code of JSP there JasperPrint ,JasperReport Can't resolve to a Type! What to do??Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code sample, it will be difficult for anyone to answer this question. But standard solution would be to keep jasper report jars in your classpath. Then import jasper classes in JSP page using:

```
<%@ page  import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for support but i have already import this.In my code i have no confusion.But i think problem with the library to add.

Comment: <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.EscapeTokenizer"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.io.*,javax.servlet.http.* "%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.* " %>

Comment: <% Statement st=null;
 ResultSet rs=null;
Connection con=null;
JasperPrint jp;
JasperReport jr;

try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/online_shop_management","root","");
 st=con.createStatement();
 
 HashMap hm=new HashMap();
 jr=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C://Users/shoab/Desktop/shop2.jrxml");
 jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,hm,con);
 JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "c://result.pdf");
 
}catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }



%>